# Why is my Samba share only writable by root?

Tags: permissions, samba, file-permissions, sudo, root

I have set up a Samba share, and it is only writable by root. For example, I can only create a folder on that share with sudo:

```sh
~$ mkdir /mnt/SHARE/somedir
mkdir: cannot create directory /mnt/SHARE/somedir: permission denied
~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/SHARE/somedir
sudo: enter password
~$ ls /mnt/SHARE/somedir | grep some
somedir
```

What to do ? The weirdest thing is, it worked until yesterday without sudo, ad I didn't change anything !

Comment: Since the working and non working, did you remount it?

Comment: @NiKiZe yes : `sudo umount /mnt/SHARE && sudo mount /mnt/SHARE`, but this and a double reboot did not change anything.